# Is there a way to control the sorting order in the user's search interface?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-maven

I'm developing AMP file for the Share tier and I want to override the search order. Currently, the sorting performed by `fullName`. In my case I need sorting by `lastName`.

In `people-finder.js` I found this line:

```
...
/**
* Build URI parameter string for People Finder JSON data webscript
*
* @method _buildSearchParams
* @param searchTerm {string} Search terms to query
*/
_buildSearchParams: function PeopleFinder__buildSearchParams(searchTerm)
{
    return "sortBy=fullName&dir=asc&filter=" + encodeURIComponent(searchTerm) + "&maxResults=" + this.options.maxSearchResults;
}
...
```

I think, that I should override `sortBy` parameter from `fullName` to `lastName`. I have done some experiments locally and saw that changes in those values make affect to the sorting.

How can I do it?

---

As Sanjay Patel noted, I created the following path and place relevant JavaScript files there:

```
share\src\main\amp\res\components\people-finder
```

I tried this way too - `share\src\main\amp\web\components\people-finder\`

But now on the embedded local Tomcat all works fine and I can see that JavaScript file was overridden:

[image]

But on the production server I get the following:

[image]

What I was tried to do:

- delete `alfresco` and `share` directories from `webapps`;
- clear the browser's  cache;
- uninstall AMP from Share and install again. Check, that it present in Share;
- [perform a full reindex with Solr](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.1/tasks/solr-reindex.html)

Nothing helps.. All of that not helped to override the `people-finder.js`

What could be the reason?

Comment: are you using SDK  with eclips for development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create same path as people-finder.js  file in eclips like share\src\main\amp\web\components\people-finder\ and place your modified file.

Comment: have you check that file is override or not?